# Liquids with high specific heats?

Tags: heat

I am wondering if there are any liquids other than water that have relatively high specific heat capacities. The tables of specific heats of common substances I have found do list ethanol (2.376 J/(g °C)), but I have not seen much else.

Comment: Liquid ammonia, as per https://www.engineeringtoolbox.com/specific-heat-capacity-d_391.html.

Comment: Liquid ammonia has the highest specific heat capacity for any liquid or solid. At room temperature, water is 2nd highest liquid. Edit: my reference is my environmental chemistry textbook by Stanley E. Manahan.

Comment: Which is why NH3 is used in regulating temperature aboard ISS (not to mention it makes a good propellant, should they run out of hydrazine ;-)